# remove background color using pure php

Tags: php, background-color

I want to remove this background color after 10 seconds using php. I don't want to use js, css. Is it possible to remove background color using pure php code?

```
<?php $running_location = '<p style="background:#E1FEE0;"></p>' ?>;
```

Comment: No. You need javascript!!

Comment: not possible at with pure php approach

Comment: I confirm it's not possible using only PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP runs on the server. All the work it does is finished before the browser receives the page.

Server side code cannot alter the page on the client after the page has been delivered.

You have to use a client side technology for this. Sensible approaches would be CSS animations or JavaScript. (NB: I'm assuming CSS animations can do this, I haven't used them enough to be sure).

Less sensible options would be to use a `refresh` either via HTML `meta` or HTTP to load an entirely new page from the server (which is identical but without the background colour).

Comment: The fact that PHP's work is *done* is only part of the story; the other part is that the browser can't interpret PHP, so asking for this to be done without frontend interpretation is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @kojiro — I'm deliberately not expounding on the crazy approach to solving the problem. :)

Comment: You could meta refresh to the same page with a GET var and then have PHP *not* echo out that refresh if that GET var is present ... it would be a really, really odd way to solve the problem but it is possible - like committing suicide by inserting your head into an Elephant's anus... possible but really, really odd.